# Regex: Positive Integers 2 or Greater

Tags: python, regex

I have a regex,

```
r'^[2-9]|[1-9][0-9]+$'
```

which I thought would work. Most all of my test conditions pass, but **-011** does not get checked by this regex, neither would **840j**. I'm hard-pressed to know why. I thought I was strictly avoiding negative numbers and non-numeric characters.

What's going on here?

Comment: How are you using this? `re.match`? `re.search`?

Comment: Looks like you’re missing parentheses ... the anchor on the left belongs to the left disjunction, not both sides of the | (likewise for the $, so you’re also gonna capture '2' rather than '23'). Something like `^(?:[2-9]|1\d)\d*$` might be what you’re after.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Semicolon made a comment pointing out your problem.

Your regex matches `-011` because it is allowed to ignore `-0` and use `[1-9][0-9]+$` to match `11`.

Your original regex has an or operator `|` which makes your regex match `^[2-9]` or `[1-9][0-9]+$` where it would seem that you want to always match a line beginning `^` then `[2-9]` or `[1-9][0-9]+` followed by a line ending `$`.

To do this you need to show the regex the proper grouping using an atomic group `(?: )`

you'll want

```
^(?:[2-9]|[1-9][0-9]+)$
```

https://regex101.com/r/B0dhYR/1